# Codeigniter doesn't load view correctly

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter project that is already up and running perfectly on the client server, now after I changed my laptop and installed xammp 1.8.2 the project is not working correctly,
the index page works just fine, and when I try to log in it only displays these two lines

> load->view('header');?>
>
> load->view('side_menu'); ?>

These two lines are the only php code in the view Home.php ,so the problem is that load view function in the controller loads the view "Home.php" but only displays the php code
The hierarchy is:

> application
>
> ```
>   controller
>      main_controller.php
>   view
>      home.php
> ```

and attached a screen shot of the displaying 
[image]
Could any one help me with that???

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, You will need to open your php document with `<?php` and end it with `?>` (not on each line as you have it.)

You will also need to use $this from the controller class.

```
<?php 
  $this->load->view('header');
  $this->load->view('side_menu');
?>
```

Comment: so I tried to add the <?php ?> and it worked but the problem is that I should change it in all the application, so do you have any idea how to change the .ini to let it allow the <? ?> tag only???

Comment: You can edit your php.ini to short_open_tag=on or you can edit your .htaccess and add php_value short_open_tag 1